# how to handle the render respose in django

Tags: python, django

first page of my application : home.html
i have written the view to render the request to "localhost:8080/contact"

```
def contact(request):
    ..
    return render(request,'template/contact.html',{'contact': [ htmlString ] })
```

Now, localhost:8080/contact is working correctly and showing the output. but i need to include the same output in home.html
i tried to add `<a href ="template/contact.html></a>` in home.html but it is now showing the results.
Can someone explain how to do this..

I am beginner in python django development.

Comment: ***i tried to add -<a href="template/contact.html></a> in home.html

Comment: What you want to do is use the django url dispatcher namespaces and named urls. Please see this link to understand how to incorporate this in your application: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !! I also used - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/language/ . Thank you again for the direction...